# change dragzone on the fly

Tags: javascript, interact.js

Interact.js library.

I have a multiple elements, each have its own interactable instance.
How to switch between instances while dragging?
So drag will be continued with another element.

Task sounds so strange, but it's simple - I made an choice-selector for small screens - when user click an element and "start draggging", it's stays at place, but Y-axis is for "roller" that change current selection, X-axis (when delta is big) will start real dragging. But with new element, not one was clicked before.

And all i need is change drag source during switch from "roller" phase to "real drag" phase.

Something like

```
event.interaction.stop();
event.interaction.start({ name: 'drag' }, anotherInteractable, anotherElement);
```

Don't work.

Thanks for any ideas.

p.s. I can make the single interactable instance per application that handle all that draggable elements, but the question will remain almost same - change interacting element on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I must make a "roller" phase without interactions.
Only onmove listener with controlling button pressed state.

When user start a "drag" phase after making his choice,
the real interaction will start with already defined object.